# App crashes when adding TextChangedListener

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, listener

I'm trying to add TextChangedListener to my EditText:

```
        statusText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.statusText);
        //Everythig is ok here...
        statusText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //After this moment app crushes with Null pointer error
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
            }
        });
```

My log:

```
    12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bresiu.elemelek/com.bresiu.elemelek.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at com.bresiu.elemelek.MainActivity.onTabSelected(MainActivity.java:213)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:570)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:499)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:485)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at com.bresiu.elemelek.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:107)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-09 02:29:25.198: E/AndroidRuntime(5167):     ... 11 more 
12-09 02:29:27.068: E/GetJar SDK(5181): PackageMonitor: doOnReceive(): failed
12-09 02:29:27.068: E/GetJar SDK(5181): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access the application key
12-09 02:29:27.068: E/GetJar SDK(5181):     at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor.doOnReceive(PackageMonitor.java:113)
12-09 02:29:27.068: E/GetJar SDK(5181):     at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor.access$000(PackageMonitor.java:62)
12-09 02:29:27.068: E/GetJar SDK(5181):     at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor$1.run(PackageMonitor.java:87)
12-09 02:29:27.068: E/GetJar SDK(5181):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-09 02:29:30.628: E/GetJar SDK(5576): PackageMonitor: doOnReceive(): failed
12-09 02:29:30.628: E/GetJar SDK(5576): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access the application key
12-09 02:29:30.628: E/GetJar SDK(5576):     at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor.doOnReceive(PackageMonitor.java:113)
12-09 02:29:30.628: E/GetJar SDK(5576):     at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor.access$000(PackageMonitor.java:62)
12-09 02:29:30.628: E/GetJar SDK(5576):     at com.getjar.sdk.data.metadata.PackageMonitor$1.run(PackageMonitor.java:87)
12-09 02:29:30.628: E/GetJar SDK(5576):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I've checked my layout.xml and everything there is ok.
I think this is caused by the FragmentActivity (my app implements tabs).
What additional informations should I add to better explein problem?

MainActivity:

http://pastebin.com/NAiw8VFe

Comment: Check if statusText is null.

Comment: I've added android:text="@string/editText" editText="" to my empty EditText, and problem still occurs.

Comment: I've checked if statusText is null with this method: if (statusText==null) {toast: is null}, and toast showed. It is correct method to comparing? statusText.equals(null) method is not working (app crushing)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/25KFLxqq

Comment: This is my tab1.xml. I had a similar problem with toggle button, and I solved it by moving setOnCheckedChangeListener from onCreate to: onTabSelected method that manages my tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content view is `R.layout.main`, but you are requesting a value from tab1. It seems that your setting the view inside of the tab. I recommend that you move all of your setting action listeners to your tab interface, in `onCreateView`. Reference the right view by:

```
statusText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.statusText);
```

Comment: You're right. Thank You.
I temporarily changed SetContentView to (R.layout.tab1) while selecting the tab1. The application is still crushing, but at least I know where the problem lies... And editText listener is working properly.
In that case, I have to move the whole code to be executed in tab1.xml to a new class? I used the tutorial on this page: http://www.lucazanini.eu/2012/android/tabs-and-swipe-views/?lang=en
Can you then show me where I need to put an invocation class when you select a specific tab? Something like this:
When tab1 isSelected -> change class to tab1.java